# Varieties of packaging a Vert.x application, and deploying it

Tags: java, deployment, vert.x, packaging

I recently started to try developing a Vert.x application. Its reactive manner is good and understandable for me, but I was not very sure about patterns of packaging a Vert.x application, and patterns of deploying it. ("Deploying" here means deploying the entire application, not deploying a verticle.)

I looked for some documents and articles, then I saw at least :

- Run through `mvn / gradle run(Mod)` from a source code directory
- Use a `vertx` command to "deploy" a verticle with `.java` source file(s)
- Build a Fat JAR
- (Extra: Embedding it in another Java application http://vert-x.github.io/embedding_manual.html)

It is interesting that those kinds of deployment are possible, but I was not very sure of any other packaging/deployment method, and how many variations of packaging/deployment styles are available for Vert.x.

Some of them did not look like, to be honest, good production-ready deployment methods to me especially in terms of the manner of immutable deployment.

Q1. Does Vert.x have a good summary / document for patterns of packaging and deploying an entire Vert.x application, especially in production?

Q2. What are advantages and disadvantages for each pattern?

Q3. Any commentary how a Vert.x application starts up internally?  (I looked into some code under `io/vertx/core/cli/`, and I saw it is spawning another JVM process. It was not very to understand its bootstrapping architecture quickly...)

Comment: If you need more in depth vert.x consulting reach out using the link in my profile

Answer (score 1):

I avoid the vert.x launcher and use regular deployment patterns.

1. Compile the code into a fat jar using maven or gradle
2. Put the fat jar into a docker image
3. Deploy the docker image

This way everything runs from your main function

Here is a starter app for vertx that you can clone and run the following commands on : https://github.com/asad-awadia/vertx-starter

`mvn clean compile install package` to create the fat jar

`mvn compile jib:dockerBuild` to build the docker image

`mvn compile jib:buildTar` to build the tar of the docker image

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah, I knew about that "embedded" approach from http://vert-x.github.io/embedding_manual.html  But how about the performance? They say they strongly recommend to apply `PlatformManager`, otherwise it cannot utilize Vert.x's scaling benefts easily.

Comment: That is not correct.  Nothing to do with scaling

Comment: Okay, it turned out that http://vert-x.github.io/embedding_manual.html is too old -- information of Vert.x v2.

Answer (score 0):

I got some information about the "Embedding" approach from the Vert.x mailing list and a GitHub Issue. Let me share it as one of answers.

http://vert-x.github.io/embedding_manual.html is so old and obsolete, which is about Vert.x v2. The Vert.x lead said :

> that's very old, nobody should ever read this anymore.

- https://groups.google.com/g/vertx/c/HAhl5dJ2PMw
- https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/4496

(But, I still keep this question open so that the question could collect some more other patterns for knowlege.)